# tensorflow installation on pycharm with anaconda 5.2

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm, anaconda

for  some  reason  I can't install `tensorflow` or  any  library  in `pycharm`  with anaconda  5.2   and  when I try I get this  message :
Solving environment: ...working... done

### Package Plan

environment location: C:\Users\magshimim\Anaconda3\envs\untitled3

added / updated specs: 
    - tensorflow

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

```
_tflow_select:       2.2.0-eigen                
absl-py:             0.6.1-py36_0               
astor:               0.7.1-py36_0               
blas:                1.0-mkl                    
ca-certificates:     2018.03.07-0               
gast:                0.2.0-py36_0               
grpcio:              1.16.1-py36h351948d_1      
h5py:                2.8.0-py36h3bdd7fb_2       
hdf5:                1.10.2-hac2f561_1          
icc_rt:              2017.0.4-h97af966_0        
intel-openmp:        2019.1-144                 
keras-applications:  1.0.6-py36_0               
keras-preprocessing: 1.0.5-py36_0               
libprotobuf:         3.6.1-h7bd577a_0           
markdown:            3.0.1-py36_0               
mkl:                 2018.0.3-1                 
mkl_fft:             1.0.6-py36hdbbee80_0       
mkl_random:          1.0.1-py36h77b88f5_1       
numpy:               1.15.4-py36ha559c80_0      
numpy-base:          1.15.4-py36h8128ebf_0      
openssl:             1.1.1a-he774522_0          
protobuf:            3.6.1-py36h33f27b4_0       
scipy:               1.1.0-py36h4f6bf74_1       
six:                 1.11.0-py36_1              
tensorboard:         1.12.0-py36he025d50_0      
tensorflow:          1.12.0-eigen_py36h67ac661_0
tensorflow-base:     1.12.0-eigen_py36h45df0d8_0
termcolor:           1.1.0-py36_1               
werkzeug:            0.14.1-py36_0              
zlib:                1.2.11-h62dcd97_3
```

Preparing transaction: ...working... done
Verifying transaction: ...working... failed

> SafetyError: The package for mkl located at
>   C:\Users\magshimim\Anaconda3\pkgs\mkl-2018.0.3-1 appears to be
>   corrupted. The path 'Library/bin/mkl_avx2.dll' has a sha256 mismatch. 
>   reported sha256:
>   17890fde268606da2dc279a2c887102ce316c04960d23e20ec5429368605755d
>   actual sha256:
>   852c0ca54a62bd4c8de59984dc9698b6f7d9d880f6d3bbe5f4a5558e7be1fa77
>
> CondaVerificationError: The package for mkl located at
>   C:\Users\magshimim\Anaconda3\pkgs\mkl-2018.0.3-1 appears to be
>   corrupted. The path 'Library/bin/mkl_avx512.dll' specified in the
>   package manifest cannot be found.
>
> CondaVerificationError: The package for mkl located at
>   C:\Users\magshimim\Anaconda3\pkgs\mkl-2018.0.3-1 appears to be
>   corrupted. The path 'Library/bin/mkl_avx512_mic.dll' specified in the
>   package manifest cannot be found.
>
> CondaVerificationError: The package for mkl located at
>   C:\Users\magshimim\Anaconda3\pkgs\mkl-2018.0.3-1 appears to be
>   corrupted. The path 'Library/bin/mkl_core.dll' specified in the
>   package manifest cannot be found.

What should I do to fix that?

Comment: Somehow your mkl package in the conda cache became corrupted. Maybe you can try to clean the cache using `conda clean` command and try to install tensorflow again.

Comment: I had this problem too, and conda clean --all fixed it.

Comment: Had the same. Try https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/66084/88005

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem too, and conda clean --all fixed it